# Convert an object's attributes and values to a list of {name: attribute and val: value}

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the most quick and efficient way to convert an object such as

```
items = [{"science":0,"english":3,"math":4}]
```

to a list like:

```
items = [{
    "name": "science",
    "value": "0"
}, {
    "name": "english",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "name": "math",
    "value": "4"
}];
```

I also need an efficient way to convert from the second format back to the original format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = $.map(items[0], function(v,k) {
    return {name:k, value:v};
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YDzQ6/)

and back again:

```
var obj = {};

$.each(arr, function(k,v) {
    obj[v.name] = v.value;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YDzQ6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

イオニカ ビザウ's solution is really nice. To convert back to your original one-object array, you just need to use

```
var newItems = {}
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  newItems[items[i].name] = items[i].value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple for loop, pushing the objects into an array.

```
items = [{"science":0,"english":3,"math":4}];

var item = items[0];

var finalItems = [];
for (var key in item) {
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key) continue;
    finalItems.push({
       name: key,
       value: item[key]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [{"science":0,"english":3,"math":4}]
var new_items = [];
for(var i in items[0]) {
    new_items.push({
    name : i,
    value: items[0][i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert JS object to JSON string

```
items = [{"science":0,"english":3,"math":4}]
JSON.stringify(items);
```

Convert a string to JSON object

```
JSON.parse(string);    //string: json string
```